# distinct rows with group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I have one table:

```
id_object | version | document
------------------------------
1         | 1       | 1 
1         | 2       | 2 
2         | 1       | 3 
2         | 2       | 1 
2         | 3       | 2 
1         | 1       | 3
```

I want to show only one row by object with the version (max) and the document. I have tried the following"

```
Select Distinct
  id_object ,
  Max(version),
  document
From
  prods
Group By
  id_object, document
```

and I get this result

```
1         | 1       | 1
1         | 2       | 2
2         | 1       | 3
2         | 2       | 1
2         | 3       | 2
1         | 1       | 3
```

As you can see, I'm getting the entire table. My question is, why?

Answer (score 2):

Since you group by `id_object` **and** `document`, you won't get your desired result. That is because `document` is different for each `version`.

```
select x.id_object, 
       x.maxversion as version,
       p.document
from 
(
   Select id_object, Max(version) as maxversion
   From prods
   Group By id_object
) x
inner join prods p on p.id_object = x.id_object 
                   and p.version = x.maxversion
```

You first have to select the `id_object` with the `max(version)`. That can be joined with the actual data to get the correct `document`.

You have to do that because you can't select columns that are not in your `group by` clause, except you use a aggregate function on them (like `max()` for instance).

(MySQL can select non aggregated columns, but please avoid that since the outcome is not always clear or even predictable)

Answer (score 0):

```
select prods.id_object, version, document
from prods inner join
(select id_object, max(version) as ver
from prods
group by id_object) tmp on prods.id_object = tmp.id_object and prods.version = tmp.ver
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a05e0/2)**

```
SELECT p.id_object, 
       p.version, 
       p.document
FROM prods p
WHERE p.version = (SELECT Max(version)
                   FROM prods
                   WHERE id_object = p.id_object)
```

Result:

```
| ID_OBJECT | VERSION | DOCUMENT |
----------------------------------
|         1 |       2 |        2 |
|         2 |       3 |        2 |
```